# Chained Payments

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I would like to know is there any other companies offering a service similar to Paypal's Chained payments?

We are looking for a service to support something like the following.

A customer purchases a product from a supplier using a providers software package. The supplier gets 90% of the sale while the provide take a 10% commission. The customer gets charged a single transaction from the supplier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use PayPal?

Comment: Firstly because we have been waiting months for PayPal to approve us. Secondly I would like to know what else is available so we can make the best choice when choosing a payment solution. I contacted Wepay today and they offer a similar service but not in Australia which we require.